# c# How can I export a shared Outlook calendar to excel?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I want to be able to send a designated calendar of a shared contact to Excel.  I can send information from my calendar but cannot send the calendar of a shared contact.  This is the code I have for my own calendar:

```
    private void ButtonClick()
    {

        //open excel with 1 sheet
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet caldendarWorksheet = newWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing,Type.Missing,1,Type.Missing) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
        caldendarWorksheet.Name = "CalendarView";

        //accesses outlook to get the calendar

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application ol = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder blab = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items ItemGet = blab.Items.Restrict("[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment'");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items ItemGet = blab.Items;
        int iNumContacts = ItemGet.Count;

        if (iNumContacts != 0)
        {
            // the index i is 1-iNumContacts,
            int i = 1;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem c = ItemGet[i] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem;



        }

    }
```

This only works for my personal calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you don't login to the account of the contact but to whatever account is default/currently open on the computer... you need to specify the calendat of the contact in this line (sufficient rights needed!)

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder blab = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: How this solved the problem? Is exactly what you had done there.. =/ I still can't get the itens of shared calendars! =/